# Create two seprate blocks within a child that are independent and inline (Banner with two blocks within)

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I'm trying to create a parent block that has two smaller block that are independent of each other

example website: http://cardoneuniversity.com/

html(within the header)

```
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="client-login">
      <div class="login-left">
        <h2>The best way to start diggin'!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="login-right">
        <div class="login-form">
          <span class=member">Already a member?</spam>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

more code after the header but that's for the background content

the CSS (relating to the code I posted)

```
header .header-content {
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding:100px 15px;
text-align:center;
}

header .client-login{
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
}

header .login-left {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 50px;
text-align: left;
}

header .login-right {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 50px;
text-align: right;
}
```

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do: 
[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to create a "landing banner" with a login option for the right, but that is a journey I'll travel soon

I've attempted using the "text-align:justify" but that led me no where. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried giving your `.login-left` and `.login-right` a width of 50%?

Comment: Use `float: left;` and `float: right;`.

Comment: float seemed to work O: 
Thank you! 

I havent tried the width of 50% no, but I'll play with that as well